# When dealing with a hierarchical status, should the model, or the data-store manage that state?

Tags: c#, database-design, architecture, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

We have a hierarchical data store (currently in SQLite) where each item has both a Flag property (get/set) and a ChildHasFlagSet property (get only, but cached.)  This way, when displaying the heirarchy in the UI, users can quickly drill down to find flagged items.

To clarify, when an item's flag is set, internally it runs up the parents and makes sure each one's ChildHasFlagSet is set to true. If the item's flag is cleared however, it queries each level for any other children that have their flag set.  This way, ChildHasFlagSet is efficiently stored so retrieval is quick and no parsing of child hierarchies is needed.

What I'm struggling with is who has ownership of the ChildHasFlagSet property: should it be the model/app, or the data store (currently SQLite.)

If it's in the model, that means if you were to retrieve a child far down in the hierarchy, then you would have to load all of its ancestors and set them as well.  This means you'd need to maintain some sort of lookup to ensure there is only ever one instance of an item.

On the flip-side, if we implement this logic in the database via triggers for instance, then you have the possibility that objects in memory are out of sync with the database. Sure you could make them refresh, but if you have to refresh them, you'd have to get them anyway, so you're right back to the model-management approach.

Any thoughts on different ways to handle this?

M

Comment: Are you using Linq? if Linq then you can easily add a property wich counts the children, then you need no flag (if I understood right your question)

Comment: I didn't really follow this.  LINQ is just a way to query something. I'm talking about setting the ChildHasFlagSet property.  In other words, who is responsible for setting that field, the data store or the model. (I've edited the question to be more clear.)

Comment: If you are using Linq, then your model are Entities, and extending an Entity with a computed property is something really simple, so no, it's not just a way to query but also to modeling.

Comment: A computed property is querying because it doesn't have the answer itself. It has to calculate (i.e. query) it.  And again, think about it. If you have something with ten levels deep and each level adds a factor of ten, then you would be querying an *INSANE* number of objects because you're querying down the hierarchy and each child would have to respond.  By bubbling up from the bottom as I said, you'd at most only set ten objects, one per level.  That's why this can't be a calculated field.  Performance would die.

Comment: Ok, I missed the part about "efficiently stores", sorry

Comment: I might be missing something, but if the user selects a child at a given level in the hierarchy, won't all of it's ancestors have already been loaded?

Comment: In that case, yes, but sometimes you may query the database and get things at a deeper level to start.  It doesn't seem like a good idea to load all the objects in memory, which is why I was leaning towards the data store, but then as mentioned, I have the refresh issue for existing objects.